# cross platform macro for silencing unused variables warning

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-c++, clang, suppress-warnings

In porting a large piece of C++ code from Visual Studio (2008) to Xcode (4.4+), I encounter lines such as:

```
UNUSED_ALWAYS(someVar);
```

the `UNUSED_ALWAYS(x)` (through `UNUSED(x)`) macro expands to `x` which seems to silence Visual C++ just fine. It's not enough for Clang  however.

With Clang, I usually use the `#pragma unused x` directive.

The `UNUSED_ALWAYS` and `UNUSED` macros are defined in an artificial `windows.h` header which I control that contains a number of utilities to help Xcode compile Windows stuff.

Is there a way to define `UNUSED(x)` to expand to `#pragma unused x`? I tried this, which Clang fails to accept:

```
#define UNUSED(x) #pragma unused(x)
```

I also tried:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)
```

Which seems to work. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Any reason why you don't just get rid of the unused vars? You can omit the var name in the function's argument list in C++.

Comment: I can't: the variable is used when compiling on windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup - you can use this approach for GCC and Clang:

```
#define MON_Internal_UnusedStringify(macro_arg_string_literal) #macro_arg_string_literal

#define MONUnusedParameter(macro_arg_parameter) _Pragma(MON_Internal_UnusedStringify(unused(macro_arg_parameter)))
```

although mine did have the `(void)` approach defined for clang, it appears that Clang now supports the stringify and `_Pragma` approach above. `_Pragma` is C99.

Comment: I didn't know about the `_Pragma` variation. I guess that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

```
(void)x;
```

is fine; has always worked for me. You can't usually expand a macro to a #pragma, although there is usually a slightly different pragma syntax that can be generated from a macro (_Pragma on gcc and clang, __pragma on VisualC++).

Still, I don't actually need the (void)x anymore in C++, since you can simply not give a name to a function parameter to indicate that you don't use it:

```
int Example(int, int b, int)
{
   ... /* only uses b */
}
```

works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yep except the parameter is used under some set of compile-time conditional compile directive. Additionally, the current case I am facing is not about a parameter but about a local variable. Finally, I try to be minimally intrusive, ie not change the original source code if not necessary, to minimize the time it get accepted at the other end (it still needs to compile and work under Windows).

Answer (score 1):

`#define` and `#pragma` both are preprocessor directives. You cannot define one macro to expand as preprocessor directive. Following would be incorrect:

```
#define MY_MACRO   #if _WIN32
```

MY_MACRO cannot expand to `#if _WIN32` for the **compiler**.

Your best bet is to define your own macro:

```
#define UNUSED(_var) _var
```

Comment: `#define UNUSED(_var) _var` doesn't work with Clang. It still reports the variable as unused.

Comment: #define UNUSED(_var) if(_var>(_var+1)) {}, or something like. Optimizer will remove such bogus instruction.